# How to Extract all Urls from href under a but it seems to give me an error all the time

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
category_tag = soup.find_all('div' , {'class': '_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8'})
```

Output of category_tag:

```
<div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318158031">Action &amp; Adventure</a></div>,
 <div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318052031">Arts, Film &amp; Photography</a></div>,
 <div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318064031">Biographies, Diaries &amp; True Accounts</a></div>,
 <div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318068031">Business &amp; Economics</a></div>,
 <div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318073031">Children's &amp; Young Adult</a></div>,
 <div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318104031">Comics &amp; Mangas</a></div>,
 <div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318105031">Computing, Internet &amp; Digital Media</a></div>,
 <div class="_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8" role="treeitem"><a href="/gp/bestsellers/books/1318118031">Crafts, Home &amp; Lifestyle</a></div>,
```

Now the problem is, I am not able to extract `href` from ''. It keeps showing error.

I have already tried:

```
category_url_tag = category_tag.find('a')['href']
```

But it keeps showing an error.

```
category_url = []
for tag in category_tag:
    category_url.append(tag.get('href'))
print(category_url)
```

This printed a list containing `None`.

Comment: can you provide the URL you're trying to scrape?

Comment: @NazmulHasan looks to me like https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/ this [kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rijulbajaj/scraping-amazon-bestselling-books-by-genre/notebook) might be helpful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select your elements more specific and use `id` and `tag` structure over dynamic classes:

```
soup.select('#zg-left-col a')
```

or to be more strict, to use only path that starts with specific pattern:

```
soup.select('#zg-left-col a[href^="/gp/bestsellers/books"]')
```

So `list` could be created via `lis comprehension`:

```
['https://www.amazon.in'+a.get('href') for a in soup.select('#zg-left-col a[href^="/gp/bestsellers/books"]')]
```

##### Example

This deals with `dict comprehension` to get only unique urls and on top also the category name:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/').text)


{'https://www.amazon.in'+a.get('href'):a.text for a in soup.select('#zg-left-col a[href^="/gp/bestsellers/books"]')}
```

##### Output

```
{'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318158031': 'Action & Adventure',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318052031': 'Arts, Film & Photography',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318064031': 'Biographies, Diaries & True Accounts',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318068031': 'Business & Economics',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318073031': "Children's & Young Adult",
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318104031': 'Comics & Mangas',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318105031': 'Computing, Internet & Digital Media',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318118031': 'Crafts, Home & Lifestyle',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318161031': 'Crime, Thriller & Mystery',
 'https://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/22960344031': 'Engineering',...}
```

Comment: ```
for a in soup. Select('#zg-left-col a[href^="/gp/bestsellers/books"]'):
    category_url.append('https://www.amazon.in'+a.get('href')) ```  
Then this should give me a list right? Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the div and all. You should find the  inside of the div.

Please check the following code. It should give you the expected result.

```
category_tag = soup.find_all('div' , {'class': '_p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-item__1rdKf _p13n-zg-nav-tree-all_style_zg-browse-height-large__1z5B8'})
categories = [(cat.find('a').text, cat.find('a')['href']) for cat in category_tag[1:]]
```

Comment: Your code works, but can u explain why
```category_url_tag = category_tag.find('a')['href']```
This didn't work?

Comment: category_tag is a list. you have to iterate over the list and find them one by one. for example, you can try with category_tag[0].find('a')['href']